# Is there a Way I can rearrange characters in a given string using a modified set of index values?

Tags: java, string, parsing, indexing

Say I have the string: "Polish". which is indexed as: P=0,O=1, L=2, I=3, S=4, H=5

I want to be able to type something like

```
" word1.arrangebyindex(051423) "
```

and have word2 equal PHOSLI

I want to be able to type in any combination of index values and have it rearranged to a new word.

I'm trying to write a program that will rearrange a given word in the following way:

The first character of the word is followed by the last character of the word which is followed by the second character and then the second last character of the word and so on.  If the given word has an odd number of characters, then the middle character is repeated again. For example, given the word **"mouse"** it should be encoded as **"meosuu"**

Comment: Your question is unclear; and it lacks the one fundamental thing each newbie is beaten up for: there is **no** evidence of you trying anything yourself to solve the problem. Suggestion: visit the [help] and like a total newbie, read again about how/what to ask here. Definitely not like this.

Comment: But to answer your question: yes, sure. Most things are possible to be done in software.

Comment: 'For example, given the word "mouseit" should be encoded as "meosuu"' - Hey, what happened to the "i" and the "t"?  Is that example correct?

Comment: GhostCat - I do not appreciate the comment. I asked this in a hurry and therefore didn't have time to ask it properly. I will update my question

Answer (score 1):

I suggest making a hashmap, which allows the user to enter in a letter, which would be the key and a number, which would be the value.

Once you associate all the letters with the number as a key and a value (such as P: 0 and H:5), then you can use your hashmap to create a string based on the numbers given to you.

Break each number down by digits (note that it will be more difficult to implement if a word is associated with a multiple digit number) and add to the string depending on what number you have called.

Here's the hashmap api: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Just look at the method summary and try those. I doubt you'll need much else out of the rest of the api.

Answer (score 0):

If you use HashMap then key as integer and value should be character because if string = **APPLE** then 0-A 1-P 2-P 3-L 4-E.

or you should go through this way:

```
public class ModifiedIndex {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = in.nextLine();
        char [] ch = str.toCharArray();
        String s ="";
        int i=0;
        int j = str.length()-1;
        if(str.length()%2 == 0)
        {
            for(int k = 0; k < str.length()/2; k++)
            {   
                    s = s+ch[i] +ch[j];
                    i++;
                    j--;

            }
        }
        else
        {
            for(int k = 0; k < str.length(); k++)
            {   if(i<=j)
                {
                    s = s+ch[i] +ch[j];
                    i++;
                    j--;
                }

            }

        }
    }

}
```